# Replace brackets only when they are after a dot

Tags: java, regex

I have to replace every

```
. (some string)
```

with

```
. \n==some string==\n
```

This doesn't work since I need to keep every occurrence of (string) that isn't after a dot:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\(", "\n==");
str = str.replaceAll("\\) ", "==\n");
```

How can I convert `(some string)` to `\n==some string==\n`, only if it's preceded by a full stop?

Comment: What does `alny` mean?

Comment: Where are the brackets here? I only see parens

Comment: @fge See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket, esp. the second and third paragraphs. In British English it's common to refer to parentheses as brackets.

Comment: sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have two `replaceAll` functions. Just a single replaceAll function which uses a capturing group based regex would be enough.

```
str.replaceAll("\\. \\(([^)]*)\\)", ". \n==$1==\n");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bH6yT0/3)

Comment: Upvote for not using the overused `.*?` but `[^)]*` instead! However, using a `Pattern` and `Matcher` is even better (meh, disallowing +1 in comments is an outright pain)